# Nesting methods advisable?

Tags: c#

Basically, say I have a method:

```
string MyMethod(string someVar);
```

And I need to use the return value in another method, is it advisable to do:

```
string myString = AnotherMethod(MyMethod(someString));
```

rather than:

```
string anotherString = MyMethod(someString);
string returnValue = AnotherMethod(anotherString);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with design patterns - it is about coding style.

Comment: internally i do not see any performance benefits in either ways because AFAIK both creates an internal memory to hold the return value of the method. But i shall looking upon the readability purposes here. Since the nested method does not take too many parameters, so i would go for the first style because it does not increases the line lenght nor complexity in reading.

Comment: ARe you looking for any particular good/bad criteria? I'd be surprised if this made any difference to speed./efficiency and after that the only thing to worry about is readability and that is subjective really. I'd probably opt for the latter purely because if debugging it becomes a bit easier to see exactly what value is geting passed to `AnotherMethod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing and debugging purposes (setting breakpoints/inspecting the results from each call separately) the longer version is the one I would prefer.

Regarding speed/efficiency there should be no measurable diference IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use the longer version - it is more readable and makes debugging easier.

Calling a method in the parameter list of another method can be confusing to the reader.

There is a minor impact on memory usage with the longer version, as you have one additional variable that needs to be allocated, but this would be minimal.

Comment: With regards to the memory allocation would it not need to allocate that memory to get the value of the nested function anyway before passing it on? It might not be explicit but surely it must still be there somewhere... (I should add that I am still relatively new at these sorts of things).

Comment: @Chris - I am talking about the additional allocation for the variable.

Comment: Yeah, I think I see what you mean now. I'm staring at the IL linqpad has generated for the two methods and realising I need to learn IL to fully appreciate all of what is going on. ;-) But I see that of course in the first example although in practice it is the same in theory the local variable could be used again later which is not the case with the nested one.

Comment: @Chris - correct. And the compiler doesn't have enough information to eliminate the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

i would also prefer 2nd option.
cause it is less complex to understand and use too.

Answer (score 0):

The longer one is more readable and easy to debug.
It is quite easy to set a breakpoint on the line of

```
string anotherString = MyMethod(someString);
```

Also, you can add watch on the varieable "anotherString" as well.